# Magento, list a few order details

Tags: php, magento

I'm new to Magento. I'm trying to list some order details (after the purchase has been made).
I'm trying the following code to get the whole amount of order, product id and order id. But this doesn't give the expected results. Any ideas how to rewrite this to work?

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $order) {
    $id = $order->getIncrementId();
    $amount = $order->getFinalPrice();
    $product_id = $order->getSku();
    echo $id;
    echo $amount;
    echo $product_id;
    }
```

Comment: Those `->getXxx()` functions are often (not always) implemented as magic from the `Varien_Object` superclass such that if the object has no value at that key, it simply outputs nothing, with no error. So since a `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` object has no (direct) sku, you're likely to get only the `$id` and `$amount` output.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right road:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $order){
    $increment_id = $order->getIncrementId();
    echo $increment_id . ":<br/>";
    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach ($ordered_items as $item){
        echo $item->getSku() . " @ " . $item->getPrice() . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

The reason being, the `sales/order` model fetches it's info from the `sales_flat_order` table, whereas the items (`sales/order_item`) fetch their information from `sales_flat_order_item`.

Comment: +1, but I suspect OP would probably rather have `->getAllVisibleItems()` rather than `->getAllItems()`.

Comment: The script makes the whole page blank. Maybe the reason is that the script wants to process ALL existing orders. How could I implement checking sum of all orders of SPECIFIC client based on his e-mail. I know that I can get e-mail by: Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
 but where to put it in your code? maybe as somekind of a filter? I tried loadByEmail function but it didn't work. The script I'm using is below, but it's shows some irrelevant numbers on the order confirmation page. On other pages the result seems to be O.K. :

Comment: $customer_email = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getEmail();
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email',array('like'=>$customer_email));

foreach($collection as $order){
    //do something
    echo round($order->getGrandTotal(),2);
}